# Round the edges of table

Tags: html, css, zurb-ink

I'm trying to round the edges of the table from below but it rounds in wrong way what should I do

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  <style>


#outlook a { 
  padding:0; 
} 

body{ 
  width:100% !important; 
  min-width: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; 
  -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
}

.ExternalClass { 
  width:100%;
} 

.ExternalClass, 
.ExternalClass p, 
.ExternalClass span, 
.ExternalClass font, 
.ExternalClass td, 
.ExternalClass div { 
  line-height: 100%; 
} 

#backgroundTable { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  width:100% !important; 
  line-height: 100% !important; 
}

img { 
  outline:none; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%; 
  float: left; 
  clear: both; 
  display: block;
}

center {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 580px;
}

a img { 
  border: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td { 
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse !important; 
}

table, tr, td {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

hr {
  color: #d9d9d9; 
  background-color: #d9d9d9; 
  height: 1px; 
  border: none;
}

/* Responsive Grid */

table.body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table.container {
  width: 580px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: inherit;
}

table.row { 
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  
}

table.container table.row {
  display: block;
  
}

td.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

table.columns,
table.column {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table.columns td,
table.column td {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px; 
}

table.columns td.sub-columns,
table.column td.sub-columns,
table.columns td.sub-column,
table.column td.sub-column {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

td.sub-column, td.sub-columns {
  min-width: 0px;
}

table.row td.last,
table.container td.last {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

table.one { width: 30px; }
table.two { width: 80px; }
table.three { width: 130px; }
table.four { width: 180px; }
table.five { width: 230px; }
table.six { width: 280px; }
table.seven { width: 330px; }
table.eight { width: 380px; }
table.nine { width: 430px; }
table.ten { width: 480px; }
table.eleven { width: 530px; }
table.twelve { width: 580px; }

table.one center { min-width: 30px; }
table.two center { min-width: 80px; }
table.three center { min-width: 130px; }
table.four center { min-width: 180px; }
table.five center { min-width: 230px; }
table.six center { min-width: 280px; }
table.seven center { min-width: 330px; }
table.eight center { min-width: 380px; }
table.nine center { min-width: 430px; }
table.ten center { min-width: 480px; }
table.eleven center { min-width: 530px; }
table.twelve center { min-width: 580px; }

table.one .panel center { min-width: 10px; }
table.two .panel center { min-width: 60px; }
table.three .panel center { min-width: 110px; }
table.four .panel center { min-width: 160px; }
table.five .panel center { min-width: 210px; }
table.six .panel center { min-width: 260px; }
table.seven .panel center { min-width: 310px; }
table.eight .panel center { min-width: 360px; }
table.nine .panel center { min-width: 410px; }
table.ten .panel center { min-width: 460px; }
table.eleven .panel center { min-width: 510px; }
table.twelve .panel center { min-width: 560px; }

.body .columns td.one,
.body .column td.one { width: 8.333333%; }
.body .columns td.two,
.body .column td.two { width: 16.666666%; }
.body .columns td.three,
.body .column td.three { width: 25%; }
.body .columns td.four,
.body .column td.four { width: 33.333333%; }
.body .columns td.five,
.body .column td.five { width: 41.666666%; }
.body .columns td.six,
.body .column td.six { width: 50%; }
.body .columns td.seven,
.body .column td.seven { width: 58.333333%; }
.body .columns td.eight,
.body .column td.eight { width: 66.666666%; }
.body .columns td.nine,
.body .column td.nine { width: 75%; }
.body .columns td.ten,
.body .column td.ten { width: 83.333333%; }
.body .columns td.eleven,
.body .column td.eleven { width: 91.666666%; }
.body .columns td.twelve,
.body .column td.twelve { width: 100%; }

td.offset-by-one { padding-left: 50px; }
td.offset-by-two { padding-left: 100px; }
td.offset-by-three { padding-left: 150px; }
td.offset-by-four { padding-left: 200px; }
td.offset-by-five { padding-left: 250px; }
td.offset-by-six { padding-left: 300px; }
td.offset-by-seven { padding-left: 350px; }
td.offset-by-eight { padding-left: 400px; }
td.offset-by-nine { padding-left: 450px; }
td.offset-by-ten { padding-left: 500px; }
td.offset-by-eleven { padding-left: 550px; }

td.expander {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

table.columns .text-pad,
table.column .text-pad {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

table.columns .left-text-pad,
table.columns .text-pad-left,
table.column .left-text-pad,
table.column .text-pad-left {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

table.columns .right-text-pad,
table.columns .text-pad-right,
table.column .right-text-pad,
table.column .text-pad-right {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Block Grid */

.block-grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
}

.block-grid td {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}

.two-up td {
  width:270px;
}

.three-up td {
  width:173px;
}

.four-up td {
  width:125px;
}

.five-up td {
  width:96px;
}

.six-up td {
  width:76px;
}

.seven-up td {
  width:62px;
}

.eight-up td {
  width:52px;
}

/* Alignment & Visibility Classes */

table.center, td.center {
  text-align: center;
}

h1.center,
h2.center,
h3.center,
h4.center,
h5.center,
h6.center {
  text-align: center;
}

span.center {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

img.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.show-for-small,
.hide-for-desktop {
  display: none;
}

/* Typography */

body, table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, td { 
  color: #222222;
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif; 
  font-weight: normal; 
  padding:0; 
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left; 
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  word-break: normal;
}

h1 {font-size: 40px;}
h2 {font-size: 36px;}
h3 {font-size: 32px;}
h4 {font-size: 28px;}
h5 {font-size: 24px;}
h6 {font-size: 20px;}
body, table.body, p, td {font-size: 14px;line-height:19px;}

p.lead, p.lede, p.leed {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height:21px;
}

p { 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

small {
  font-size: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #2ba6cb; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover { 
  color: #2795b6 !important;
}

a:active { 
  color: #2795b6 !important;
}

a:visited { 
  color: #2ba6cb !important;
}

h1 a, 
h2 a, 
h3 a, 
h4 a, 
h5 a, 
h6 a {
  color: #2ba6cb;
}

h1 a:active, 
h2 a:active,  
h3 a:active, 
h4 a:active, 
h5 a:active, 
h6 a:active { 
  color: #2ba6cb !important; 
} 

h1 a:visited, 
h2 a:visited,  
h3 a:visited, 
h4 a:visited, 
h5 a:visited, 
h6 a:visited { 
  color: #2ba6cb !important; 
} 

/* Panels */

.panel {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.sub-grid table {
  width: 100%;
}

.sub-grid td.sub-columns {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Buttons */

table.button,
table.tiny-button,
table.small-button,
table.medium-button,
table.large-button {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table.button td,
table.tiny-button td,
table.small-button td,
table.medium-button td,
table.large-button td {
  display: block;
  width: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #2ba6cb;
  border: 1px solid #2284a1;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

table.tiny-button td {
  padding: 5px 0 4px;
}

table.small-button td {
  padding: 8px 0 7px;
}

table.medium-button td {
  padding: 12px 0 10px;
}

table.large-button td {
  padding: 21px 0 18px;
}

table.button td a,
table.tiny-button td a,
table.small-button td a,
table.medium-button td a,
table.large-button td a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

table.tiny-button td a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table.small-button td a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

table.medium-button td a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

table.large-button td a {
  font-size: 24px;
}

table.button:hover td,
table.button:visited td,
table.button:active td {
  background: #2795b6 !important;
}

table.button:hover td a,
table.button:visited td a,
table.button:active td a {
  color: #fff !important;
}

table.button:hover td,
table.tiny-button:hover td,
table.small-button:hover td,
table.medium-button:hover td,
table.large-button:hover td {
  background: #2795b6 !important;
}

table.button:hover td a,
table.button:active td a,
table.button td a:visited,
table.tiny-button:hover td a,
table.tiny-button:active td a,
table.tiny-button td a:visited,
table.small-button:hover td a,
table.small-button:active td a,
table.small-button td a:visited,
table.medium-button:hover td a,
table.medium-button:active td a,
table.medium-button td a:visited,
table.large-button:hover td a,
table.large-button:active td a,
table.large-button td a:visited {
  color: #ffffff !important; 
}

table.secondary td {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border-color: #d0d0d0;
  color: #555;
}

table.secondary td a {
  color: #555;
}

table.secondary:hover td {
  background: #d0d0d0 !important;
  color: #555;
}

table.secondary:hover td a,
table.secondary td a:visited,
table.secondary:active td a {
  color: #555 !important;
}

table.success td {
  background: #5da423;
  border-color: #457a1a;
}

table.success:hover td {
  background: #457a1a !important;
}

table.alert td {
  background: #c60f13;
  border-color: #970b0e;
}

table.alert:hover td {
  background: #970b0e !important;
}

table.radius td {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

table.round td {
  -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
  -moz-border-radius: 500px;
  border-radius: 500px;
}

/* Outlook First */

body.outlook p {
  display: inline !important;
}

/*  Media Queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  table[class="body"] img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] center {
    min-width: 0 !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .container {
    width: 95% !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .row {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
    
  }

  table[class="body"] .wrapper {
    display: block !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .columns,
  table[class="body"] .column {
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    float: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    display: block !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .columns,
  table[class="body"] .wrapper.first .column {
    display: table !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] table.columns td,
  table[class="body"] table.column td {
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .columns td.one,
  table[class="body"] .column td.one { width: 8.333333% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.two,
  table[class="body"] .column td.two { width: 16.666666% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.three,
  table[class="body"] .column td.three { width: 25% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.four,
  table[class="body"] .column td.four { width: 33.333333% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.five,
  table[class="body"] .column td.five { width: 41.666666% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.six,
  table[class="body"] .column td.six { width: 50% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.seven,
  table[class="body"] .column td.seven { width: 58.333333% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.eight,
  table[class="body"] .column td.eight { width: 66.666666% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.nine,
  table[class="body"] .column td.nine { width: 75% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.ten,
  table[class="body"] .column td.ten { width: 83.333333% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.eleven,
  table[class="body"] .column td.eleven { width: 91.666666% !important; }
  table[class="body"] .columns td.twelve,
  table[class="body"] .column td.twelve { width: 100% !important; }

  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-one,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-two,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-three,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-four,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-five,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-six,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-seven,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eight,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-nine,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-ten,
  table[class="body"] td.offset-by-eleven {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] table.columns td.expander {
    width: 1px !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .right-text-pad,
  table[class="body"] .text-pad-right {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .left-text-pad,
  table[class="body"] .text-pad-left {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .hide-for-small,
  table[class="body"] .show-for-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }

  table[class="body"] .show-for-small,
  table[class="body"] .hide-for-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
}

  </style>
  <style>

    table.facebook td {
      background: #3b5998;
      border-color: #2d4473;
    }

    table.facebook:hover td {
      background: #2d4473 !important;
    }

    table.twitter td {
      background: #00acee;
      border-color: #0087bb;
    }

    table.twitter:hover td {
      background: #0087bb !important;
    }

    table.google-plus td {
      background-color: #DB4A39;
      border-color: #CC0000;
    }

    table.google-plus:hover td {
      background: #CC0000 !important;
    }

    .template-label {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family:Freestyle Script;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    .callout .wrapper {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .callout .panel {
      background: #ECF8FF;
      border-color: #b9e5ff;
    }

    .header {
      background: #999999;
    }

    .footer .wrapper {
      background: #ebebeb; 
       border-radius:0px 0px 20px 0px !important; 
    }
    
    
    
    .footer1 .wrapper {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius:20px 20px 0px 0px !important;
    }
    
    .footer h5 {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    table.columns .text-pad {
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

    table.columns .left-text-pad {
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

    table.columns .right-text-pad {
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

      table[class="body"] .right-text-pad {
        padding-left: 10px !important;
      }

      table[class="body"] .left-text-pad {
        padding-right: 10px !important;
      }
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="row header">
    <tr>
      <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>

          <table class="row header">
            <tr>
              <td class="center" align="center">
                <center>

                  <table class="container">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="wrapper last">

                        <table class="twelve columns">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="six sub-columns last" style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle;">
                              <p></p></br>
                              <span class="template-label">CitynU account activation</span>
                              <p></p>       
                            </td>
                            <td class="expander"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table class="container">
            <tr>
              <td>
              
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <table class="row footer1">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper last">

                      <table class="twelve columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dear {user-name},</h5></br>
                            <p class="lead">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thanks for your signup on {shopname}</p>
                            <p class="lead">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please click the link to activate your account {clickhere} </br>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;or</br>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;by pasting the below URL in your browser window. </br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{websiteurl}</p></br>
                            <p >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;For any issues while accessing your account. Please feel free to contact us on below &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;details.</p>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      
                      
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                

                <table class="row footer ">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">

                      <table class="six columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="left-text-pad">

                            <h6>Connect With Us:</h6></br>

                            <table class="tiny-button facebook">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <br>

                            <table class="tiny-button twitter">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <br>

                            <table class="tiny-button google-plus">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <a href="#">Google +</a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                    <td class="wrapper last">

                      <table class="six columns ">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="last right-text-pad">
                            <h6>Contact Info:</h6></br>
                            <p><strong>Address:</strong> City Markets Online Services Pvt. Ltd</p>
                            <p><strong>Phone:</strong> </p>
                            <p><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:info@citynu.com">info@citynu.com</a></p>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>

                <table class="row">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper last">

                      <table class="twelve columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                            <center>
                              <p style="text-align:center;">&#169; City Markets Online Services Pvt. Ltd. 2013-2014</p>
                            </center>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

              <!-- container end below -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result of my try. It rounds in the middle too. What should I do to make it rounded on the edges only
[image: screenshot]

Comment: wow that's a lot of code! Try only including the relevant code that's necessary for the question.

Comment: @Danield sorry just concentrate on the .footer part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to have the border radius both sides of the table then do this

```
    .footer .wrapper{
  background: #ebebeb; 
  border-radius:0 0px 0 20px
}
    .footer .last {

       border-radius:0px 0px 20px 0px !important; 
    }
```

otherwise

```
    .footer .wrapper{
  background: #ebebeb; 
}
    .footer .last {

       border-radius:0px 0px 20px 0px !important; 
    }
```

I made a pen so you can have a play around if you need to.
http://codepen.io/dave_agilepixel/pen/dCKqy

Answer (score 1):

I've added one more class called `.first` and remove the `border-radius` from class `.wrapper`

Here is the Code for class `.first`

```
.footer .first {
      background: #ebebeb; 
       border-radius:0px  0px  0px 20px !important; 
    }
```

Here is the another class called `.last`

```
.footer .last {
      background: #ebebeb; 
       border-radius:0px 0px 20px 0px !important; 
    }
```

Here is the Working **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jikimaco/1/)**.

Here is the screenshot also.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have added an ID `leftwrapper` to the left one and `rightwrapper` to the right one. I removed the `border-radius` on the wrapper and gave the ID's I've made the styles:

```
#leftwrapper {
border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
}

#rightwrapper {
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}
```

[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3E4z/)

**NOTE:**
Some browsers (IE 8 and lower) do not support border radius, so it could be useful to add a vendor prefix for this. The code then would look like:

```
#leftwrapper {
-ms-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
}

#rightwrapper {
-ms-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
}
```

Comment: this is not a webpage. It's a simple mailer better not to use CSS3 features.

Comment: Some might view their mails in their web browsers.

Comment: why making the things so complicated, what if the OP doesn't provide the online version link.. then?

Comment: In my opinion it's not making things complicated, it's making things work. You add 2 lines and you're sure that it works for everyone. Some people don't have software to open their mails, they go to, for example www.gmail.com and read their e-mails from there.

Comment: I am not agree with you. It seems you are worried only about gmail users; won't you consider the people using outlook to access the mail.

Comment: I'm not only worried about gmail users, that's why I said 'for example' gmail users. There is also www.outlook.com where you see the e-mail on your webbrowser. Wether you agree is not something I should care about, don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be harsh. I'm just noting that it could be useful to add vendor prefixes as people might look their e-mail up in their webbrowser.